# Delta Faucet: Maximum Gallons Per Minute with New Aerator

Tags: bathroom, water, faucet

If I bought a 1.5GPM new replacement aerator, would the faucet emit 1.2GPM or would it increase to 1.5GPM ? I see a lot of delta faucets like this

https://www.deltafaucet.com/bathroom/product/B2596LF

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you have, and what you're hoping for, which would guide our answer. Would you add this to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: does the aerator have a built in pump? ... if not, then do not expect an increase in flow

Answer (score 1):

This faucet comes from the factory with the Delta RP61340 aerator which is a 1.5 gpm aerator.

This would mean that the faucet's internal valve and/or water delivery configuration is what limits GPM delivery to 1.2. So... **NO**, replacing the aerator won't help you because it comes with a 1.5 but is certified at 1.2

Comment: I actually emailed Delta, many times, and they said it would increase, you are free to email customer service, interesting topic

Comment: Interesting, if you follow your own link and look at the Q & A, Delta answers a question about the faucet and clearly states "Thank you for your question, MThomas! The Delta model B2596LF uses the RP61340 aerator which is 1.5 gpm aerator -15/16"-27 male. Please feel free to contact us directly if you have any questions or need further assistance". So how does Delta rate a faucet at 1.2gpm **if the factory supplied 1.5gpm aerator is the only restriction??**

Comment: There is something fishy in Denmark/Delta...

Comment: Also, if you emailed the manufacturer "many times" about this, why would you re-ask the community about it?